# Setting an array of songs using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have 5 songs which i need to play one after the other, and it must loop from the first song after finishing the 5th song. 
How do  I use the MediaPlayer to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public class MediaPlayerExample extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
 int [] songs;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
int current_index = 0; 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

songs= new int[] {R.raw.song1,R.raw.song2,R.raw.song3,R.raw.song4};

mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, songs[0]);

mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

mediaPlayer.start();

}
@Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        play();

    }

 private void play()
    {
        current_index = (current_index +1)% 4;
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(songs[current_index]);

        try
        {   
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
            afd.close();
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! but there is some syntax error on this line -> AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(songs[current_index]);
context cannot be resolved..

Comment: sorry but i wrote it on the notepad but it works fine check your array of songs since songs[current_index] always return an integer and be sure that you name your song correctly in the raw folder :) wish u luck

Comment: No problem! So should I pass the Context as a parameter to the the play method?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use CountDownTimer for this. CountDown timer has give you facility to do this one by one ::

```
MediaPlayer mp_xmPlayer2  = new MediaPlayer();
mp_xmPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bg_music_wav);   


 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    CountDownTimer cntr_aCounter = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            mp_xmPlayer2.start();
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            //change music name
          }
        };
        cntr_aCounter.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
int[] songs = new int[]{R.raw.ab_hai_hamari_bari, R.raw.ab_khel_jamay_ga, R.raw.ab_khel_ke_dikha_psl_official_song, R.raw.chakka_choka_islamabad_united, R.raw.dil_dil_pakistan_junaid, R.raw.duniya_se_aagay, R.raw.hai_jazba_junoon_tho_himmat_na_haar, R.raw.hum_hain_pakistani_junaid, R.raw.jeet_ki_lagan, R.raw.jeetay_ga_pakistan_dedicate, R.raw.josh_e_junoon_pakistan_cricket, R.raw.karachi_kings_official, R.raw.lahore_qalandar_official, R.raw.multan_sultan_official, R.raw.peshawar_zalmi, R.raw.quetta_gladiator, R.raw.stand_up_for_the_champions};
```