# Create A More Complex Soundboard

Tags: android, eclipse

So I have created a basic soundboard but am now looking to update the sound board to version 2.0

I would like to have a soundboard where when somebody clicks on a button the soundboard plays a random sound in that particular category.

Here is my basic soundboard code........

Your help is very much appreciated.

```
package com.example.benandhollysoundboard;

import android.R.layout;
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View;  
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class myMenu extends Activity {

MediaPlayer ben, holly, gaston, plum, queenthistle, kingthistle, robot, wiseoldelf, lucy;


ImageButton Ben, Holly, Gaston, Plum, Queenthistle, Kingthistle, Robot, Wiseoldelf, Lucy;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.Layout.activity_main);

    Ben = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ben);

    Ben = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Ben);
    Ben.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ben.start();
        }
    }); 

    holly = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.holly);

    Holly = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Holly);
    Holly.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            holly.start();
        }
    }); 

gaston = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gaston);

    Gaston = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Gaston);
    Gaston.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            gaston.start();
        }
    });

    plum = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.plum);

    Plum = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Plum);
    Plum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            plum.start();
        }
    }); 

    robot = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.robot);

    Robot = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Robot);
    Robot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            robot.start();
        }
    }); 

    wiseoldelf = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wiseoldelf);

    Wiseoldelf = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Wiseoldelf);
    Wiseoldelf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            wiseoldelf.start();
        }
    }); 

lucy = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lucy);

    Lucy = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Lucy);
    Lucy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            lucy.start();
        }
    });

    kingthistle = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kingthistle);

    Kingthistle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Kingthistle);
    Kingthistle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            kingthistle.start();
        }
    }); 

    queenthistle = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.queenthistle);

    Queenthistle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Queenthistle);
    Queenthistle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            queenthistle.start();
        }
    }); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i'am not into android developping but i think you could save the filenames of each category in an array and then if you press the button generate a random number and puts it in the array

for example (generates random int between 1 - 10)

```
int rand = (int) (Math.random()*10+1);
```

and then

something like

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int rand = (int) (Math.random()*10+1);
            Array[rand].start();
        }
    });
```

hope i could help ;)

Comment: @ WarGodNT How would I assign numbers to files? Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @user2270318 Not shure i never worked with "MediaPlayer" but brobably you could make an Array like here ;) --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383387/setting-an-array-of-songs-using-mediaplayer

Comment: @user2270318 I'm Glad if i could help :)